# Unable to implement Admob package in Android app

Tags: android, gradle, admob

I am trying to use Admob Ads in an Android app.

My `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo.d"emo
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.7"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.github.kaustubhk24:NumberToWords-Library:434afa327b'
}
```

When I try to add Adview I get the following issue:

```
This operation requires the library com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+.
Problem:
Inconsistencies in the existing project dependencies found.
Version incompatibility between:
- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1 and:
- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1
With the dependency:
- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:[2.5.1] versus:
- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.3.1
The project may not compile after adding this library. Would you like to add it anyway?
```

If I still add and try to run, then I get:

```
C:\Users\Kaust\StudioProjects\demo\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:103:
AAPT: error: unexpected element <property> found in <manifest><application>
```

When I remove the following, the app works perfectly:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0'
```

Thanks for any advice how to add the Admob package.

Comment: You're using incompatible library versions.  Try updating everything to newest.

Comment: can you guide which you mean?